# How to validate date with today date using php?

Tags: php

I am creating subscription website using php. I'm storing time and date in format 2016-03-07 14:35:05 in one field i want to valid that using `php` from date of created i want to valid for one month if one month completed i want to show 1 month completed else nothing.What am i doing wrong? i tried [this](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2011/11/04/how-to-check-if-a-date-is-more-or-less-than-a-month-ago-with-php/) tutorial .

```
$my_date=date("d/m/Y", strtotime("2012-12-24 12:13:14"));        
echo (strtotime($my_date) < strtotime('1 month ago'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my recollection, if you're using a `/` in the date field, the american `m/d/Y` is assumed rather than `d/m/Y`. I would suggest you try the following:

```
$my_date=date("d-m-Y", strtotime("2012-12-24 12:13:14"));
echo (strtotime($my_date) < strtotime('1 month ago'))
```

Or

```
$my_date=date("d.m.Y", strtotime("2012-12-24 12:13:14"));
echo (strtotime($my_date) < strtotime('1 month ago'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$today=date("d-m-Y h:i:s");
echo (strtotime($today) < strtotime('1 month ago'))
```